# Android Getting user location latitude and longitude using the GoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, android-studio

I am working on getting the user's latitude and longitude using the GoogleApiClient and this is what I have done so far. I followed the Udacity tutorial on Google Maps to do this. I have done exactly as it showed on Udacity but my latitude and longitude are not displaying like it does for the instrutor.

There are no errors, so I am not able to see where the mistake is.
I have Google Play Services version 10.2.0 installed and entered that in the dependencies section of the build.gradle app. 
Any help is much appreciated.

```
package com.example.udacitylocation;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
{
private final String LOG_TAG = "LaurenceTestApp";
private TextView txtOutput;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    txtOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutput);
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
{
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create(); // Another way to write a new object
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10); // Always write in milliseconds

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, location.toString());
    txtOutput.setText(location.toString());
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.udacitylocation.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/txtOutput"
    android:text="Location Goes Here"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.udacitylocation">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What are you getting ? Location[fused ....] something like that?

Comment: @tahsinRupam On my phone, "Location goes here" is displayed because I hardcoded that in the xml file. Nothing else is displayed

Comment: @DimaRostopira Thanks! I will check it out.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

add this internet permission in your androidManifest.xml , I hope this will work for you.... 
[Go to this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGhYB.png)